# convert invalid datetime in ruby to valid datetime

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have a react frontend and a ruby backend to my web application. I sent over to my ruby backend a new javascript date object which was then converted into this invalid datetime in ruby:

```
"2018-01-10T05:00:00.000Z"
```

Is there anyway to convert this to a datetime that reads as follows?

```
"1/5/2018, 12:00:00 AM"
```

Yes I do want it to remain a string.

Comment: What did you send exactly? How did you convert? If you want to get an answer please provide a code which you think works incorrectly and explain what did you expect and what did you receive(and preferably what did you try to resolve it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
var date = new Date( "2018-01-10T05:00:00.000Z") //Wed Jan 10 2018 10:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
a.toLocaleString() // output : "1/10/2018, 10:30:00 AM"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is strptime: https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strptime/class

If your React code is sending Rails the time in the format "1/5/2018, 12:00:00 AM" and it's being automatically recognized incorrectly, you can force Rails to recognize a custom format like so:

DateTime.strptime('1/5/2018, 12:00:00 AM', '%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S %p')

Once you run it through that, Rails should be able to identify each of the fields. If you're trying to read it back in a more React-friendly way, strftime (shown below) will help with that.

You should also check out the strftime docs for all the formatting options you can use with strptime: https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime